# Exchange type issues in RabbitMQ..Consumer expects "fanout" but producer actual is "topic"

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a docker environment where messaging service(rabbitmq) and my services(myapp) are configured in docker. I try to consume the messages published by myapp.
myapp produces the messages of type "fanout" in a given message channel and in consumer code, I try setup the rabbitmq intricacies so that messages of type "fanout" can be consumed.

```
consumer sample:
factry = newConnectionFactory();
factry.setHost(MYHOST);
connection.newConnection();
chnl = connection.createChannel();
channel.exchangeDeclare("MYEXCHG","fanout",true);
.....
and so  on.
```

When consumer sets the rabbitmq thingy as shown above:
I get following PRECONDITION error: 
Caused by:

> com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol
>   method: #method(reply-code=406,
>   reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange
>   'applicationStatus' in vhost '/': received 'fanout' but current is
>   'topic', class-id=40, method-id=10)

I have enough analysed the producer code and consumer code. Still I could not narrow down the issue. My ask here is: Can i configure the channel in such a way that I will be able to accept any type of messages sent by producer.

Say Producer P1 produces msgs of type direct and P2 produces msgs of type fanout. Can i have a common consumer code so that it will be able to receive msgs produced from P1 and P2...

Comment: In case of a precondition error, make sure to check the parameters of both queue and exchange, as I was trying to fix the value of the `type` arg on the queue but it was actually a parameter of the exchange. The annotation parameters of `Queue` & `Exchange` in the `QueueBinding` annotation in the listener annotation in spring boot helped me figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its not the message type instead an exchange type. Thanks Luke Bakken for your inputs. I have reached out to the rabbitmq forum.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/6IQ4s6pmys0

Answer (score 0):

> Say Producer P1 produces msgs of type direct and P2 produces msgs of type fanout. Can i have a common consumer code so that it will be able to receive msgs produced from P1 and P2...

Messages do not have a type of `direct` or `fanout`, exchanges do. Your publisher and consumer code will have to declare *two* exchanges, one of each type.

Then, your publisher will publish to each exchange, depending on if the message should be directly routed to a queue or fanout to several queues.

Finally, your consumer will have to declare and bind queues to each exchange, and then consume from each queue.